# Image collection containing multiple relative orbit numbers in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to select images acquired from two different relative orbits in Google Earth Engine. What i tried so far is:

```
var collection_orbit = collection
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_start', 54))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_start', 113));
```

which throws the error "Image Collection Empty" while using only one of the lines above works well.

How can i add images from two different relative orbits to my image collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the way you filter, the collection is first filtered for all relative orbits 54. This collection thus only contains images from relative orbit 54. Then, you check that collection for relative orbit 113, and logically no images pass that filter. Instead, combine the filters using `ee.Filter.or()`, and then filter the collection:

```
// import collection 
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD");

// make a combined OR filter
var filter = ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_start', 54), 
                          ee.Filter.eq('relativeOrbitNumber_start', 113));

// filter the collection
var collection_orbit = collection.filter(filter);

print(collection_orbit.limit(100))
```

I assumed you are using the Sentinel-1 collection.

Comment: Or more compact: `var filter = ee.Filter.inList('relativeOrbitNumber_start', [54, 113])`